# Get FileSize of uploading image in livecode

Tags: image, livecode

I am trying to upload images in livecode with mobilePickPhoto. I succesfully done with this.But i want to restrict my uploader to upload high file size images. So i want to get the image file size before uploading .So i can check whether to upload that file or not.
Also please let me know if there is some way to compress sizes of images.
Thanks

Comment: What are you uploading the images from? For example, from the documents folder, from within your stack (an image control), or from MediaPicker?

Comment: I am using "MobilePickPhoto".In this it upload images from Library.After browsing i encode it and store it sqlite database .Then after decoding image data i used to show images in some datagrid.But i feel if images are of high file sizes , it takes too much time to decode and retrieve image.So i want to have some way ,either to compress their sizes or get file size of the images and restrict if it is having high file size.

Comment: I've edited my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, compressing pictures doesn't make sense. PNG, JPEG and GIF files are compressed already. You can try to compress with

```
put compress(the text of img "My Image") into myPictureData
```

This compresses the picture data as gzip. PHP can decompress this.

After using mobilePickPhoto, a new image control is created. You can check the size of the last image with

```
put len(the text of the last image) into mySize
```

Comment: I have tried "put len(the text of the last image) into mySize". But unfortunately it is not getting exact file size of images.

Comment: Btw you can also use `the size of the last image` and you don't really have to refer to the text, you can also do `len(the last img)`. There are simply too many ways to do it ;-)